# Creating a iOS scrollable timeline view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, ios9

I'm trying to create a timeline view in iOS that can be scrolled both horizontally (time) and vertically (cities). I'm having trouble finding if there is something made from before that I can look at for help.

The timeline view is a view that have date and time going horizontally and you can move time back and forward with moving finger on the horizontal axis. Vertically you can go future down to see the different rows (cities).

Timeline looks something like this:

```
Wed 4 Aug
---------
City A
01    02    03    04    ... time continues ->

City B
02    03    04    05

...(cities continue vertically)
```

What is the best approach to this? I been thinking about `UIScrollView`, but I have rows (cities) that need to be in place while changing the time.

I have experimented with `UIView` that has it's own `drawRect` but that seems less than brilliant to redraw each time user moves a little bit and sounds very heavy on the hardware.

I'm also thinking that different layers of `UIViews` could solve this, with top layer having the city names and the bottom layer being scrolled, but how could I solve the vertical scrolling?

Comment: i am trying to implement same..how did you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I would use a UITableView for your vertical movement, each cell within that UITableView would have a scrollView that is set to scroll horizontally.

Comment: How can I sync the scrollview of each table view cell?

Comment: However you want to. The cell will have a scroll view in it and you will put your code in the cell to control what you show in that scroll view. So you could have an array of items in the cell that you want to populate the scrollview with.

Comment: I think this could have worked to some degree, but I'm not going to go with this. I think a custom control would more fit what I need and I'm following the examples and tips from this article: http://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control